# php mysql query not executing correctly

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a weird problem with my sql script.

I have a string

```
$query = "INSERT into sms_replyid (eventid, bus_id, cell_num, sms_message) 
          VALUES ('93361357', '2162', '27761144734', 'Hoekom');";
```

But when I execute that string it inserts it to the table but eventid stays 0, if I run that exact command in cmd it works perfectly?

Any ideas why this is not inserting all the values?

Edit Full code

```
<?php session_start();

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password"); //removed u and p for posting

if (!$link)

    die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");

mysql_select_db("db", $link) //removed db name for posting

or die ("Couldn't open smss:" . mysql_error());
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$message = $_REQUEST['promo_message'];
$timeToSend = $_REQUEST['timeToSend'];
$dateToSend = $_REQUEST['dateToSend'];





    if(isset($_REQUEST['input_cell']))
    {
        $receiver = $_REQUEST['input_cell'];
        if($receiver != '')
        {
            $response_string = sendSMSPortalSchedule($message, $receiver, $sender_id, $dateToSend, $timeToSend);
            $response_string = str_replace ( "True" , "", $response_string );
//This does not work right, all gets added perfectly yet eventid stays 0 enven while all the others get the right values
        $query1 = "INSERT into sms_replyid (eventid, bus_id, cell_num, sms_message) VALUES ('$response_string', '$id', '$receiver', '$message');";

        mysql_query($query1);
        echo mysql_error();
        }
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['single_cell']))
    {
        $receiver = $_REQUEST['single_cell'];
        if($receiver != 'none')
        {
        $response_string = sendSMSPortalSchedule($message, $receiver, $sender_id, $dateToSend, $timeToSend);
        $response_string = str_replace ( "True" , "", $response_string );
        $query2 = "INSERT into sms_replyid (eventid, bus_id, cell_num, sms_message) VALUES ('$response_string', '$id', '$receiver', '$message');";
//This does not work right, all gets added perfectly yet eventid stays 0 enven while all the others get the right values
        mysql_query($query2);
        echo mysql_error();

        }

    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['sento_group']))
    {
            $array = $_REQUEST['sento_group'];
        foreach($array as $receiver)
        {
            if($receiver != 'none')
            {
                $query = 'SELECT cell_number FROM cell_groups WHERE group_id ="'.$receiver.'"';
                $result2 = mysql_query($query) or die('Fail');

                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
                {
                $response_string = sendSMSPortalSchedule($message, $row['cell_number'], $sender_id, $dateToSend, $timeToSend);
                $response_string = str_replace ( "True" , "", $response_string );
                $to = $row['cell_number'];
                $query3 = "INSERT into sms_replyid (eventid, bus_id, cell_num, sms_message) VALUES ('$response_string', '$id', '$to', '$message');";
//This does not work right, all gets added perfectly yet eventid stays 0 enven while all the others get the right values
                        mysql_query($query3);
                echo mysql_error();
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the table

```
id = INT
eventid = BIGINT(20)
bus_id = INT
cell_num = VARCHAR
sms_message = VARCHAR
```

Comment: Please post the code you use to execute the query, and the full table definition.

Comment: Is the semicolon within the SQL string supposed to be there? From what I know MySQL does not need to end with a semicolon.

Comment: @Seralize It makes no difference

Comment: @Serialize: You are right, the semicolon *shouldn't* be there. From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) `The query string should not end with a semicolon.` However I think MySQL just ignores it, so I don't think it can explain the error.

Comment: What happens when you end the script right after the query? This way we are sure no other portion of the script is modifying the table any further.

Comment: @Konerak makes no difference. What is weird about it to me is I have another script in another part of my web app that does the same insert as this and it works perfectly there.

Comment: Dude, you were asked to post relevant code, not all the code you have. Care to debug it yourself?

Comment: @Col I have been debugging this code for two days, and I think most of the code is relevant, bit I will remove non relevant code

Comment: what are results of debugging, may I ask?

Comment: and what idea of debugging you have I am interesting also. Watching the code for hours?

Comment: @Col value of query1 = INSERT INTO sms_replyid (eventid, bus_id, cell_nem, sms_message) VALUES ('93361357', '2162', '27761144734', 'Hoekom')

Comment: @Col I use Komodo on mac to step through my code. I am not a beginner

Comment: @Col off coarse I have run the script with only the essentials, and breaking it down, and building it up, and using echo to track progress, what exactly do you want to know, ask and I will add, but lets try and keep it relevant to the question at hand, and not about my debugging skills, if you can't help me I will understand.

Comment: okay, I'll repeat. did you try to get the results immediately? did you try this query alone, with no other code? NOT from console but from test script. what are the results?

Comment: @Col when running the query just by it self in the script I get the correct result in the db, that's why I don't know why this aint working

Comment: So build up the script from the "bare command which works" unto the "script you have that doesn't work". Test after every logical block. Somewhere it will stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL command itself is correct. The problem must be elsewhere.

Firstly, are you sure that the values of your parameters are correct? Try outputting the query *after* variable interpolation to see if it is correct:

```
$query1 = "INSERT into sms_replyid (eventid, bus_id, cell_num, sms_message) VALUES ('$response_string', '$id', '$receiver', '$message')";
echo $query1;
```

Seondly I notice that in you have INSERTs in multiple places. Make sure *all* of them work as expected. Remember that the one you *think* is executing may be different from the one that is *actually* executing.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, the service I was using got changed to return XML where it usually just returned an integer, this caused me to try and insert XML into my BIGINT field, which is not possible. So in the end the problem was caused by an updated service that didn't notify clients about changes.